# How to check the connection to MySQL database with RedBean?

Tags: php, redbean

How do I programmatically find out if there was an error connecting to the database via `R::setup()` in RedBean?

The object that is returned by this:

```
$ret = R::setup('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testdatabase', 'root', '');
```

is the same as the object that is returned by this:

```
$ret = R::setup('mysql:host=127.0.0.1BADBADBAD;dbname=testdatabase', 'root', '');
```

And when I try to access the database, it gives a PHP error and stops execution so I can't check the value of `$bean`.

```
$bean = R::findOne('uploadedfiles',' filename = "ok" ');
```

And so a try/catch is also not possible because RedBean does not through a proper error that can be caught.

How can I check if the connection created in `R::setup()` was successful or not programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `R::setup` inside a try/catch block?

Comment: Thanks, I tried a try/catch again around the `$bean` statement above did throw a proper error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may try to check your connection using

```
R::getDatabaseAdapter()->getDatabase()->isConnected();
```

or in another way

```
$isConnected = R::testConnection();
```

read more about [debugging](http://www.redbeanphp.com/debugging) in redbean docs

Comment: Perfect, `$isConnected = R::testConnection();` is exactly what I was looking for.